# jQuery .val() Not Able to be Converted to Int using parseInt

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, int, equation

I have tried `parseInt()` to no avail. I still get NaN errors using this code...

```js
$("#belt-length").on("input", function(){
   var length = parseInt($("#belt-length").val(), 10);
   var width = parseInt($("#belt-width").val(), 10);
   if(length > 0 && width > 0) {
    var squaremm = length * width;
    var square = squaremm / 1000000;
    $("#belt-square-meters").html(square.toString() + "m<sup>2</sup>");
   } else {
    $("#belt-square-meters").html("0.00 m<sup>2</sup>");
   };
  });
  $("#belt-width").on("input", function(){
   var length = parseInt($("#belt-length").val(), 10);
   var width = parseInt($("#belt-width").val(), 10);
   if(length > 0 && width > 0) {
    var squaremm = length * width;
    var square = squaremm / 1000000;
    $("#belt-square-meters").html(square.toString() + "m<sup>2</sup>");
   } else {
    $("#belt-square-meters").html("0.00 m<sup>2</sup>");
   };
  });
```

I have tried converting the fields to `type="number"`. I use the `.val()` method as it is my understanding that `.val()` will pull the actual value of the form field and not an object reference to the form field.

Comment: You haven't included the html code for the field whose `.val()` you're trying to get. But it looks like it can have a value that is not numeric, which causes `parseInt` to return `NaN`. The common way to fallback is using the `||` operator: `parseInt(...) || 0`

Comment: Your code [works here!](https://jsfiddle.net/hdLpxupf/)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Of course you can convert `.val()` result to integert via `parseInt`. `parseInt` method accepts string as a first parameter ([MDN. parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)), while `.val()` returns "the value of the value attribute of the FIRST matched element" ([W3Schools. jQuery val() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp)) which is string in text-input case ([W3Schools. Input Text value Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)). So there is no problem with your code and your `(length > 0 && width > 0)` NaN-protection is pretty common here.

**2.** I'd recommend do some refactoring. Extract your handlers into a single function and simplify output:

```
function processInput() {
    var length = parseInt($("#belt-length").val(), 10);
    var width = parseInt($("#belt-width").val(), 10);
    var square = '0.00';
    if(length > 0 && width > 0) {
        var squaremm = length * width;
        square = squaremm / 1000000;
    }
    $("#belt-square-meters").html(square + "m<sup>2</sup>");
}

$("#belt-length").on("input", processInput);
$("#belt-width").on("input", processInput);
```

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/D5YcsQGJzqqIUbou0rxI?p=info